# Python3 List Comprehension for n lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a way of iterating through my lists as I wish as follows:

```
a = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
b = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
c = ["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]

for x, y, z in [(x,y,z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]:
    print(x,y,z)
```

Output:

```
1 A 11
1 A 12
1 A 13
1 A 14
1 A 15
1 A 16
1 A 17
1 A 18
1 A 19
1 A 20
1 B 11
1 B 12
1 B 13
1 B 14
...etc
```

But how can I achieve the same result if my lists are stored in a list and there are n lists? e.g.

```
main_list=[["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","1"],['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"],['k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t']]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Essentially, if `main_list` contains all the lists, `zip(*main_list)` should give you what you want.

Comment: `zip` won't do it. `zip` will only give "1 A 11, 2 B 12, 3 C 13, ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
a = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
b = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
c = ["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]

from itertools import product

all_lists = [a, b, c]
for c in product(*all_lists):
    print(c)
```

Prints:

```
('1', 'A', '11')
('1', 'A', '12')
('1', 'A', '13')
('1', 'A', '14')
('1', 'A', '15')
('1', 'A', '16')
('1', 'A', '17')
('1', 'A', '18')
('1', 'A', '19')
('1', 'A', '20')
('1', 'B', '11')

... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example, the below gives the required combinations.

```
import itertools

list(itertools.product(*(a,b,c)))
```

For the mainlist -

```
main_list=[["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","1"],['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"],['k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t']]

combintns = list(itertools.product(*main_list))

# in case you're specific about output format/appearance
for i in combintns:
  print(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3])
```